# How does checking correctness with Weakest Preconditions work?

Tags: formal-languages, symbolic-execution

We have [this example](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Emsagiv/courses/asv/Symbolic%20Reasoning.pdf):

```
{true}
assume x > 1;
y := x * 2;
z := x + 2;
assert y > z;
{true}
```

They then show this:

```
{true}
wp(assume x > 1, x * 2 > x + 2) = x>1 -> x*2 > x+2
assume x > 1;
wp(y := x * 2, y > x + 2) = x * 2 > x + 2
y := x * 2;
wp(z := x + 2, y > z) = y > x + 2
z := x + 2;
wp(assert y > z, true) = y > z -> true = y > z
assert y > z;
{true}
```

I assume from reading other places that this is evaluated *backwards*, from the end to the beginning. So in steps it would be:

```
wp(assert y > z, true) = y > z -> true = y > z
wp(z := x + 2, y > z) = y > x + 2
wp(y := x * 2, y > x + 2) = x * 2 > x + 2
wp(assume x > 1, x * 2 > x + 2) = x>1 -> x*2 > x+2
```

What do the parameters mean? How do I read these statements? And how is the `wp` function implemented generally speaking, are there any public algorithms for it? Basically, what is happening here, can you break it down?

My reading is from this slide:

```
To check {P}S{Q}, prove P -> wp(S, Q)
```

So Q (the assertion) is the second parameter, and S (the statements) is the first parameter.

So then:

```
wp(assert y > z, true) = y > z -> true = y > z
```

We start with the Q which was `{true}`. We pass in the last assertion, that `y > z`. This for some reason results in "if y > z, then true = y > z", I don't know what that means, or how they derived this.

Then:

```
wp(z := x + 2, y > z) = y > x + 2
```

We want to prove Q = y > z. So it appears we substitute the values from S into Q, giving us `y > x + 2`.

Repeat this. Then we get to the end where `x>1 -> x*2 > x+2`, "if x > 1, then x*2 > x+2". So I still don't see how we derived this from the preceding statements.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transformer_semantics#Weakest_preconditions

Comment: I already looked at that page, it gives the standard derivations, but I need it spelled out like in my example, so I can see the intricacies of how it is applied.